# Unable to start up Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, vaadin, vaadin7

I created a Vaadin 7 project in Eclipse running on Tomcat 8.  I want to use EJBs, CDI, JPA in my application. Here's my `Ivy.xml`.

```
    <dependency org="org.eclipse.persistence" name="javax.persistence" rev="latest.release"/>
    <dependency org="com.vaadin" name="vaadin-cdi" rev="latest.release"/>
    <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="latest.release"/>
    <dependency org="javax.ejb" name="ejb-api" rev="latest.release"/>
```

But when I started Tomcat up, I got the below errors. Do you know why it can't find that class?

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine.StandardHost.StandardContext]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine.StandardHost.StandardContext]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5065)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: It is missing a JAR which provides the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager class....

Answer (score 2):

plain tomcat is just a servlet container, so without getting into Spring world it is only a good basis for trivial applications (no JPA, CDI, EBJs...). You should definitely look at [TomEE](https://tomee.apache.org) if you like Tomcat or [Wildly](http://www.wildfly.org) if you want to have the latest stuff from Java EE 7.

Comment: ...or any other [Java EE 7 certified application server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Certified_application_servers)